# SimpleDateFormat appears to give an incorrect result

Tags: java, date, clojure

I'm using Java 7 and Clojure 1.4 for this.

I'm writing up some database tests in Clojure for a table that contains `Date` objects, using OracleDB over `JDBC`.

I need to compare the date I receive (a `Date` object) with a `String` - so presumably I need to convert that string to a `Date` object. After some googling, I found Java's `SimpleDateFormat`.

This is what I use (with extra stuff for debugging)

```
(defn parseDate [date]
  (do (debug (str "Parsing date: " date ))
    (let [ dateobj (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "dd-MMM-YY")
           parsed (do (. dateobj setLenient false) (. dateobj parse date))]
      (debug (str "Result: " parsed)) parsed)))
```

I throw in some dates, and I get the following output..

```
Parsing date: 01-jan-12
Result: Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2012
Parsing date: 01-jan-13
Result: Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 2012
Parsing date: 00-jan-12
Result: Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2012
Parsing date: 02-jan-13
Result: Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 2012
```

That doesn't seem right, at all.

The `Date` object returned is something like this: `#<Date Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2012>`, which is clearly not equal to what I get back from the database, for example, `#<Date 2012-01-01>`.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

NOTE: I get the same result whether I use `setLenient` or not (and with either true or false).

**Answer (Courtesy of Jon Skeet [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11538275/1437524))**

I was using YY in my format string, where I should have actually used yy (Since Y is the week-year and y is the simple year).

Comment: `"dd-MMM-YY"` throws an error, it should be `"dd-MMM-yy"`

Comment: @Ankur: It may throw an error for *you*, but it clearly doesn't for the OP. I suspect you're using Java 6, which doesn't support week-year. Java 7 does.

Comment: Yep, I'm using Java 7. Sorry, should've mentioned that.

Comment: Use `y` instead of `Y` and [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're using YY instead of yy. From the docs of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `YY` refers to the *week-year* rather than the year.

Week-years are somewhat odd, and unless you *know* you want to use it, you probably don't. In particular, mixing week-year with "day of month" and "month" is almost never appropriate. You'd normally use "week-year, week-of-year, day-of-week" together.

To put it another way: the two systems are a bit like RGB and HSV for colours; it's as if you've defined a format of "red, green, hue" which doesn't make a lot of sense :)

Comment: Yep, now my Date objects have the correct date, you are indeed correct. They still don't equal the ones in the database, but I presume I should be able to modify them to match. I'll accept this one when it lets me.