# SimpleDateFormat parse return End of Year date

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I have this simple example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YY");
        System.out.println( sdf.format(new Date()));
        try {
            System.out.println(  sdf.parse("10/18/14")  );
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In the console, I'm getting 
10/18/14
Sun Dec 29 00:00:00 EST 2013

Any explanation why sdf.parse return dec 29th 2013 in stead of Oct 18th 2014

Answer (score 4):

Your format `String` is `YY` and should be `yy`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```

Per the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc (which says in part),

> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
> G         Era designator          Text            AD
> y         Year                    Year            1996; 96
> Y         Week year               Year            2009; 09
> ```

Currently you're getting the *Week year*.

When I make the above change I get (the expected)

```
10/18/14
Sat Oct 18 00:00:00 EDT 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happend here : [SimpleDateFormat appears to give an incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11538161/4088809)
Try to look if someone had the same issue first, it's easier and faster to get an answer for your problem.